# Modifying a flexible Google Sheets onEdit script to accommodate a wider range of inputs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Below is a script that allows me to combine five different onEdit functions into a single function.

```
function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() != "H12" || e.value != "submitResponse") return;
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getActiveSheet();
  var m = sh.getSheetByName("Master");
  ss.getRange(2,1,ss.getLastRow(),3).copyTo(m.getRange(m.getLastRow()+1,1,ss.getLastRow(),3)); 
  ss.getRange('H12').clearContent();
  e.range.clearContents();
}
```

I'm now hoping to make this script more flexible. See Sheet1 of my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EoOIQxWyKWOvtlCrmJNI76FAxGhzgXrE4s0F05tw2MY/edit#gid=0

It would be great if instead of limiting myself to H12, I could use the entire column of H:H to submit each corresponding row. So when I change H2 to submitResponse, it copies/pastes A2:G2 to the last row of the Master. When I change H3 to submitResponse, it copies/pastes A3:G3 to the last row of the Master. And so forth.

I tried my hand at this but no luck on execution. I guess I'm missing something.

```
​function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.range;
  var actionCol = 8;
  var rowIndex = r.getRowIndex();
  var colIndex = r.getColumnIndex();
  var colNumber = s.getLastColumn()-1;
  if (e.value == "submitResponse" && colIndex == actionCol) ;
    var sourceRange = s.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, colNumber);
    var targetRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Master").getRange(getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, colNumber);
    sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName()=='Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart==8 && e.range.rowStart>1 && e.value=="submitResponse") {
    var msh=e.source.getSheetByName("Master");
    msh.appendRow(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,7).getDisplayValues()[0]);
  }
}

function onEdit(e){
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName()=='Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart==8 && e.range.rowStart>1 && e.value=="Yes") {
    e.range.setValue('');
    var msh=e.source.getSheetByName("Master");
    msh.appendRow(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,7).getDisplayValues()[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow - this seems like it's working just fine! Gets the job done with far less code - impressive. How would I modify this code such that the cell used to trigger the code gets cleared out (i.e., "submitResponse" is cleared)? Previously I used:   e.range.clearContents(); ... but that doesn't work here. I'm trying to do it myself but your approach is pretty unique and I'm having a tough time!

Comment: Actually part of my issue is this: following submission, I want to clear not only the cell that triggered the script (i.e., submitResponse cell), but also another range of cells that I specify. My previous script worked like this:

`function onEdit(e){
....
  ss.getRange(4,1,1,24).copyTo(m.getRange(m.getLastRow()+1,1,1,14), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false); 
  ss.getRange('Y4').clearContent();
  ss.getRange('A3:X3').clearContent();
  e.range.clearContents();`

Comment: I'll be using this script in a different spreadsheet that uses different ranges, but the idea is I would clear out the cell in which I selected "submitResponse" as well as clear out the row above the row in which I select submitResponse. For this test spreadsheet let's assume I want to clear out cell H3 (which would contain submitResponse) and A2:G2 of the same sheet.

Comment: Why don't you just ask another question and give me all of the facts and it will be easier to answer.

Comment: New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61719091/google-sheets-onedit-trying-to-copy-a-row-to-a-new-sheet-by-changing-the-value