# Google Sheets onEdit - trying to copy a row to a new sheet by changing the value of a column within that same row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Please see Sheet1 of my spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EoOIQxWyKWOvtlCrmJNI76FAxGhzgXrE4s0F05tw2MY/edit#gid=0

As an example, I would like to copy the values (not formulas) of A3:G3 to the bottom row of the 'Master' sheet by changing the value in H3 to "submitResponse." Then, once that row is copied, I would like to automatically clear out cell H3, as well as range A2:G2 (the row ABOVE the row that was copied) because these will be variables that the user edits to adjust A3:G3 before it gets copied.

To help, here is a script that @Cooper built for me to push me in the right direction:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName()=='Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart==8 && e.range.rowStart>1 && e.value=="submitResponse") {
    var msh=e.source.getSheetByName("Master");
    msh.appendRow(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,7).getDisplayValues()[0]);
  }
}
```

from this previous question: [Modifying a flexible Google Sheets onEdit script to accommodate a wider range of inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61706003/modifying-a-flexible-google-sheets-onedit-script-to-accommodate-a-wider-range-of/61706146?noredirect=1#comment109170707_61706146)

Update:

```
function onEdit(e){ 
  var done = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange('Y:Y'); 
  var sh=e.range.getSheet(); 
  if (sh.getName()=='submit' && e.range.columnStart==25 && e.range.rowStart>1 && e.value=="submit") { 
    var msh=e.source.getSheetByName("db"); 
    msh.appendRow(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,24).getDisplayValues()[0]); 
    done.clearContent(); 
  } 
 }
```

Update 2:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var submitColumn = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange('Y:Y');
  var rowAbove = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange('J11:L11');
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName()=='submit' && e.range.columnStart==25 && e.range.rowStart>1 && e.value=="submit") {
    var msh=e.source.getSheetByName("db");
    msh.appendRow(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,24).getDisplayValues()[0]);
    submitColumn.clearContent();
    rowAbove.ClearContent();
  }
}
```

Comment: And what modificaitons have you triied to accomplish your goals?

Comment: This is the one I thought would work for the submitResponse cell by appending it to the end:

sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,8,1,1).clearContents();

As far as the specific ranges, I was trying variations of what I had previously but I'm having trouble integrating them with your approach.

SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1).getRange('A2:G2').clearContents();

Comment: There is  no Range Method `clearContents()`  Look here:https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: It's hackey but this worked for the submitResponse cell:

'function onEdit(e){
  var done = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange('Y:Y');
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName()=='submit' && e.range.columnStart==25 && e.range.rowStart>1 && e.value=="submit") {
    var msh=e.source.getSheetByName("db");
    msh.appendRow(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,24).getDisplayValues()[0]);
    done.clearContent();
    
  }
}'

... still unsure how to clear the row ABOVE the row that was copied. If it were a fixed row it'd be simple, but that row will vary.

Comment: Please add it to your question.

Comment: That clears all of column 25 is that what you want?

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()` is the same as `sh`

Comment: No it’s not optimal - hackey. Would prefer to only clear the cell.

Comment: So, your question here is basically that you want to clear a specific when a value changes, am I right? If A1 changes for example then B1 must get cleared am I right?

Comment: Hi @MateoRandwolf. Yes exactly - though I'd like to clear multiple ranges. So when I change H5 to "submitResponse," the following should happen: 1) Copy A5:G5 to bottom row of new sheet; 2) Clear H5; 3) Clear A4:G4 (these were variables adjusted by the user that informed A5:G5).

Comment: @MateoRandwolf See Update 2 above for an example of my latest code. I realize that code is suboptimal, but it still seems like it should work (in my novice opinion!). Column Y:Y is indeed getting cleared out (although I would prefer to only clear out the specific cell Y12 within Y:Y), but 'J11:L11' is not clearing out and it's driving me bonkers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

With `Update 2` you were really close to solve this issue. However, you had a typo, replace:

```
rowAbove.ClearContent();
```

with

```
rowAbove.clearContent();
```

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: Oh my ... that is... frustratingly embarrassing! Whew - at the very least I'm glad I wasn't going crazy when I felt that code should've been working!