# Google Sheets onEdit - clearing select content in the row above the active row in which the edit occurred

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently building out an onEdit script that clears the content of select cells upon edit. The issue I'm running into is that the cells to be cleared are dependent on the cell that was edited, so I can't use fixed ranges.

Please see Sheet2 of my spreadsheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EoOIQxWyKWOvtlCrmJNI76FAxGhzgXrE4s0F05tw2MY/edit#gid=1388181285

Below is my current attempt at this:

```
 function onEdit(e){
  var submitColumn = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange('H:H');
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName()=='Sheet2' && e.range.columnStart==8 && e.range.rowStart>1 && e.value=="submitResponse") {
    var msh=e.source.getSheetByName("Master");
    msh.appendRow(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,7).getDisplayValues()[0]);
    var rowAbove = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,7).getLastRow()-1;
    submitColumn.clearContent();
    rowAbove.clearContent();
  }
}
```

I'm trying to clear out two things:

1. Upon edit clear out the cell in column H that I changed to "submitResponse." Currently my script clears out the full column, which is not exactly what I want but it gets the job done.
2. Clear out the select cells in the rows above my target row. These rows (ex: 11,16,21,26...) are user-entered and inform the data in my target row (ex: 12,17,22,27...). Upon edit I'm trying to clear out the specific user-entered cells that informed the row I copied to the Master sheet. Currently my script – if it were working as written – would clear out the full row of user-entered cells, which is not what I want. Let me clarify with an example: when I change H12 to submitResponse, I want the following to happen: 1) A12:G12 is copied to the Master sheet; 2) H12 is cleared; 3) B11,D11:F11 is cleared. ... There may be upwards of 50 of these potential "submitResponse" rows so I'm trying to avoid fixed ranges if possible.

[Google Sheets onEdit - trying to copy a row to a new sheet by changing the value of a column within that same row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61719091/google-sheets-onedit-trying-to-copy-a-row-to-a-new-sheet-by-changing-the-value?noredirect=1#comment109173895_61719091)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName()=='Sheet2' && e.range.columnStart==8 && e.range.rowStart>1 && e.value=="submitResponse") {
    e.range.setValue('');//the edited cell
    var msh=e.source.getSheetByName("Master");
    msh.appendRow(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,7).getDisplayValues()[0]);//append data no change
    e.range.offset(-1,-5).clearContent();//clear cell B in row above
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart-1,4,1,3).clearContent();//clear D,E & F of row above
  }
}
```

Comment: Cooper you are the absolute man. Thank you so much! This is exactly what I'm looking for. And thank you for the scripting lesson on offsets. I had used them in formulas before but never in a script. Excited to implement them more moving forward. Cheers mate!

Comment: Hey Cooper - thanks again this code is great. I've noticed that while the edited cell always clears, occassionally cells B, D, E and F do not clear. I know the code is accurate and works, so it's not that, but could you think of a general explanation for that? Does having multiple "clearContent" functions sometimes cause issues? Is there an additional function I can add to ensure those clearContents get executed?

Comment: I might also guess that it has something to do with triggers coming at it to fast so the flush might actually cause more problems.

Comment: Thanks Cooper - I appreciate the help! I'll look into it and let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Further testing suggests it's mainly the final/third clearContent() where I run into issues; 2nd one seems to run fine. I'm testing activate() now but it doesn't seem to work. I'll try more later tonight.

Comment: I wasn't able to track down a solution. I caved – I reworked my spreadsheet and moved the original Column C out of there... now I can clear B, and D:F with a single clearContent function. Thanks again Cooper.

Comment: It's always nicer to rearrange your data if you can so that the program is easier to write.

Comment: Yes for sure. In this case moving around the data required a bit of legwork so I was trying to avoid it if possible... but in the end it wasn't worth the hassle so I took the time to rearrange it.