# Modifying e.range.getA1Notation() to accept wider range of inputs in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using a Google Apps script to update the active sheet's name with a cell (C6) value when another cell (I16) is updated. Currently, the script works fine when I16 is updated and the sheet is renamed as intended.

However, I would like the range of inputs to be much wider, like an A:J kind of range, or at least A1:J104. How can I achieve this?

I have also read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61706003/modifying-a-flexible-google-sheets-onedit-script-to-accommodate-a-wider-range-of) but I'm unsure of how to extract that info specific to this scenario.

The script I'm using is as follows:

```
function onEdit(e) {

if(e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'I16') return;

var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();

s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().setName(s.getRange('C6').getValue());

}
```

Any assistance will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: With the script, the following happens:

1. Upon editing cell I16, the contents of cell C6 changes via a formula. For example, when I enter "002" into cell I16, cell C6 updates to "Report-002", and so on.
2. At the same time, the script extracts the string in cell C6 and updates the name of the current sheet accordingly (i.e. the sheet is now named "Report-002".

The script works well for this specific scenario. However, I would like to trigger the script when I update a wider range of cells, and **not just cell I16**. Ideally, I'd like the script to run if I updated **any** cell in the sheet.

Does that help to clarify what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Your code doesn't really make much sense and your description of what you are trying to accomplish leaves a lot to be desired.  If you could explain in greater detail what you are trying to accomplish you would have a much greater chance of getting it because obviously you have no idea what you are doing and I'm sure  at least one of the volunteers here does.

Comment: I don't have a great idea of what I'm doing for sure – have barely ever needed to use Google Apps Script. Hope my explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.getActiveSheet().setName(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange('C6').getValue());
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mike, much appreciated. The current script achieves what I want to do partially; however, I'm hoping that the script can run (i.e. the sheet name automatically updates with the string contained in cell C6) upon editing any cell, and not just I16.

Comment: ok, see the updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much, Mike, you're great! This works perfectly. Realise it was a fairly straightforward tweak but hope this helps anyone else looking for an insight like this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Change the `if` condition to account for bounds:

```
const [/*actual row*/ar, ac] = ['rangeStart','columnStart'].map(s => e.range[s])
const [/*row start*/rs, re, cs, ce] = [1,2,3,4];//C1:D2
if(ar >= rs && ar <= re && ac >= cs && ac <= ce){
// do stuff
}
```