# Google Apps Script OnEdit only works on one specific cell, help please

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I got this work once the way I wanted but then I changed the code etc. and it didn't work anymore. But anyway here is my problem:

So I would like to have this A1Notation work on cells C3:C28. The code will only work if I remove the "C28" and run the code only in "C3". Here is the code:

```
    function onEdit(e) {
      if (e.range.getSheet().getName() + '!' + e.range.getA1Notation() === 'Sheet1!C3:C28') {
        mycode()
      }

}
```

So everything else working just fine but I can't get the range list correct. Thank you for advance!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72374548/) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try

```
function onEdit(e) {

  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === `Sheet1`) {

    if (
      e.range.rowStart >= 3 && e.range.rowEnd <= 28 &&
      e.range.columnStart === 3 && e.range.columnEnd === 3
    ) {

      // Code

    }

  }

}
```

Although this does not use A1 notation, this will only run `onEdit` on `Sheet1` in the range of `C3:C28`.

Comment: It works now! Thank you so much! I'm just learning to use Apps Script so it is nice to see that the community helps each other. :)

Comment: Enjoy! Let me know if you have any other questions